# Network: Does NAT needs in IP6

Tags: networking

As this link: 
[Things that NATs break](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/what-nats-break.html)

We see that NAT has many weak points, but the strongest point of NAT is you can use private addresses, and this is valuable in IP4: when IP addresses don't enough for all devices, so use private addresses will save many public IP addresses for your company/group ...

But at IP6, IP addresses is enough for all, so does we really need NAT in IP6 ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no NAT in IPv6. There have been some proposals, but the [IETF has frowned upon them](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4864). The address space is large enough that it will not be required, among other reasons. (read [RFC 4864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4864).)

Also, there are still private IPv6 address ranges. Instead, there are [Unique Local IPv6 Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193).

Comment: Note, this also means the other big (albeit pretty much accidental) benefit of NAT -- a gateway that semi acts as a firewall -- is gone.

Comment: @cHao, yes, RFC 4864 talks in detail about this.